How to replace text of an XML element with Ansible?
The below XML-file lists JARs with versions:
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Files>
<!-- ... -->
 <File Check="Y">public/foo-1.1.0.jar</File>
 <File Check="Y">public/bar-2.3.11.jar</File>
</Files>

I need to update the foo to version 1.2.1. I'd like to use the Ansible xml-module -- but I can't figure out the syntax, so that it would:

Replace any existing entry for foo, if it refers to a different version.
Add a new entry for foo, if none exists.
Optional: leave only a single entry for foo -- with the specified version -- even if there were duplicate ones before (such as from earlier botched upgrade-attempts).

The only approach that comes to mind is to use two tasks: remove any existing entries (state=absent) first, and then create a new one.
Can anyone suggest, how the same can be accomplished in one go?

"I'd like to use the Ansible xml module", may we ask why? What kind of software are you updating? Where is it installed? How is it installed? How do you like to update it? This all could help to step back and see if there comes a simple solution in mind which might not be on the table yet. Otherwise, "How the same can be accomplished in one go?" I would say be using the template module or implementing a Custom Filter or Module or several playbook tasks.

You could also use shell module in combination w sed, instead of xml module.

The issue with the couple delete/add is that the idempotency could become hard to maintain. In your actual XML is there really nothing else that can differentiate the elements describing public/foo*.jar from another of the files nodes?

"Editing" an existing XML file and "programming" in a kind of IF THEN ELSE manner will become in Ansible cumbersome and error-prone, see the simplified minimal example
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'files.xml') }}"
    FOO_PATH: public/foo-1.2.1.jar

  tasks:

  - name: Convert XML to YML
    set_fact:
      YML: "{{ XML | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  - name: Show content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ YML }}"

  - name: Update path
    ansible.utils.update_fact:
      updates:
        - path: "YML.Files.File.0['#text']"
          value: "{{ FOO_PATH }}"
    register: updated

  - name: Show updated content
    debug:
      msg: "{{ updated.YML | ansible.utils.to_xml }}"

  - name: Write out XML file
    copy:
      dest: updated.files.xml
      content: "{{ updated.YML | ansible.utils.to_xml }}"

resulting into an output of
TASK [Convert XML to YML] ******************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Show content] ************************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg:
    Files:
      File:
      - '#text': public/foo-1.1.0.jar
        '@Check': Y
      - '#text': public/bar-2.3.11.jar
        '@Check': Y

TASK [Update path] *************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Show updated content] ****************************
ok: [localhost] =>
  msg: |-
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Files>
            <File Check="Y">public/foo-1.2.1.jar</File>
            <File Check="Y">public/bar-2.3.11.jar</File>
    </Files>

and the respective file with content. But it will already break if the input file contain not the correct order like in
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<Files>
<!-- ... -->
 <File Check="Y">public/bar-2.3.11.jar</File>
 <File Check="Y">public/foo-1.0.0.jar</File>
 <File Check="Y">public/foo-1.1.0.jar</File>
</Files>

Documentation

from_xml filter – Convert given XML string to native python dictionary
update_fact module – Update currently set facts
to_xml filter – Convert given JSON string to XML


Declaring the Desired State seems to be the better approach. A minimal example with Inline Templating
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:

    XML: "{{ lookup('file', 'files.xml') }}"
    FOO_PATH: public/foo-1.2.1.jar

  tasks:

  - name: Convert XML to YML
    set_fact:
      YML: "{{ XML | ansible.utils.from_xml }}"

  - name: Gather and set path
    set_fact:
      BAR_PATH: "{{ (YML.Files.File | selectattr('#text', 'contains', 'bar') | first)['#text'] }}"

  - name: Create XML file
    copy:
      dest: created.files.xml
      content: |
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <Files>
          <File Check="Y">{{ FOO_PATH }}</File>
          <File Check="Y">{{ BAR_PATH }}</File>
        </Files>

will just create the file in the necessary final state.
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Files>
  <File Check="Y">public/foo-1.2.1.jar</File>
  <File Check="Y">public/bar-2.3.11.jar</File>
</Files>

Documentation

copy module – Copy files to remote locations - Parameter content
template module – Template a file out to a target host


from_xml and to_xml? How interesting, thanks for the idea!

Try a powershell script
using assembly System.Xml.Linq
$input_filename = 'c:\temp\test.xml'
$output_filename = 'c:\temp\test1.xml'

$doc = [System.Xml.Linq.XDocument]::Load($input_filename)
$files = $doc.Descendants('Files')

$foos = [System.Linq.Enumerable]::Where($files, [Func[object,bool]]{ param($x) [string]$x.Value.StartsWith('public/foo')})
$pattern = '(public/foo-)(.*)(.jar)'
$newVersion = '1.2.1'

foreach($foo in $foos)
{
   $version = $foo[0].Value
   $newValue = $version -replace $pattern, '$1xyz$3'
   $newValue = $newValue -replace 'xyz', "$newVersion"

   $foo.FirstNode.SetValue($newValue)
}
$doc.Save($output_filename)


Thanks, but that's not Ansible...

Whereby this answer the question "How the same can be accomplished in one go?", or in other words by a Custom Filter or Module, the Ansible Control Node runs on Linux with Python and usually there is no PowerShell installed. So there are several dependencies in order to get your example running.
